# Удаление настроек из каталога ~/.config вместе с deb-пакетом

Tags: debian, apt-get, deb, пакеты

Для хранения настроек программа использует каталог `~/.config/ProgramName`. Я хочу чтобы при полном удалении командой `sudo apt-get purge ProgramName` также удалялась папка с настройками. Написал вот такой `postrm` сценарий:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

case "$1" in
    purge)
        rm -r ~/.config/ProgramName
    ;;

    *)
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

При удалении ошибка:

> rm: невозможно удалить '/root/.config/ProgramName': Нет такого файла или каталога

Почему-то ищет каталог в папке суперпользователя, а не текущего пользователя. При использовании команды `rm -r $HOME/.config/AutoScreenshot` всё тоже самое.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Во-первых, откуда скрипту знать, какой пользователь текущий? Во-вторых, что если пользователей несколько?

Comment: Ну и вообще во всём интернете пишут, что apt/dpkg не предназначен для удаления пользовательских файлов

Comment: Я как-то не подумал про то, что несколько пользователей могли использовать программу, поэтому удалять папку с настройками следует для каждого из них.

Comment: Я считал, что как-раз apt get purge должен выполнять полную очистку вместе с настройками.

Comment: Вместе с **системными** настройками, но не пользовательскими

Comment: Но почему? И как тогда пользовательские правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант из предыдущего ответа в принципе неплох, но шелл фильтровать по `nologin` не совсем корректно. Там может быть к примеру `/bin/false`

Более логичным кажется грепать шелл, аналогичный текущему.

Если немного допилить предыдущий ответ, обход всех домашних каталогов будет выглядеть примерно так

```
for i in $(getent passwd | grep "$SHELL" | cut -d: -f6); do echo "rm -f -r $i/.config/ProgramName"; done
```

Comment: По-моему грепать какой угодно шелл в принципе нелогично, потому что он может быть любой

Answer (score 0):

получить домашние каталоги пользователей можно так

```
getent passwd | grep -v 'nologin$' | cut -d: -f6
```

при удалении используй ключ -f чтоб не было ошибки.